# FIrebase mobile authentication and save user to database

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am authenticating users through mobile number in Firebase. Currently I am in the test mode. My idea is that if the mobile number has not been used previously then a new user is created. Here I am using a function saveUserToFirebaseDatabase. I was of the idea that this function would verify whether the user already exists. But the way I have written it as of now it doesnot. Hence, when the user logs out and logs in, the values of the child, which I inserted somewhere else are lost. That is obviously because the function saveUserToFirebaseDatabase is recreating the user.

Here I observe an interesting thing, which is that the uid that is created for the mobile number remains same for all login. This gets me further confused about the saveUserToFirebaseDatabase function. Here is my code for saving the user in the database.

```
private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(){
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
    val user = User(uid, "","+91"+MobileNumber.text.toString(), "")
    ref.setValue(user)
}

class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val mobile: String, val mail: String)
```

The user authentication routine is as per the Firebase documentation and works smoothly. Can someone please explain how this function saveUserToFirebaseDatabase is working. Why does the uid always remain constant, although, the other childs username and mail get reset to ""

Comment: Didnt you create the function `saveusertofirebasedatabase`?

Comment: Yes I did. My confusion is on the fact that why the uid when the user is recreated remain the same. I will edit my question since there is some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This your code:

```
private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(){
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
val user = User(uid, "","+91"+MobileNumber.text.toString(), "")
ref.setValue(user)
}

class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val mobile: String, val mail: String)
```

First, you retrieve the `userId`, then you add the `userId` under `users` in the database.

After that you create an instance of class `User` and add the `user` to the database.

This `userId` is the id of the currently logged in user. If a new authenticated user logs in then a new user will be added to the database.

The `userId` is generated randomly it's creation has nothing to do with the email or Facebook or any other login type.